# Angular I can't get Image from Server

Tags: angular

Here for example is a link:
http://www.kalliany.at/SPG/getWassersport_withID.php?id=1
if you go onto it you can find this:

```
{"id":"1","sportart":"Paddeln","disziplin":"Kanu","kurzbez":"Einer-Kajak","bild":"large\/Kanu_01_large.jpg","beschreibung":"Die \u00d6sterreicherin (geborene Deutsche) Yvonne Schuring im \"Flachwasser\"-Kajak"}
```

This section:
"bild":"large/Kanu_01_large.jpg"
is a picture it is saying and I am trying to display that on my website

These are my model&interface for it

```
export class WassersportdetailRaw {
    id: string;
    sportart: string;
    disziplin: string;
    kurzbez: string;
    bild: string;
    beschreibung: string;
}



import { WassersportdetailRaw } from "./wassersportdetail.interface";

export class Wassersportdetail implements WassersportdetailRaw{

    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public sportart: string,
        public disziplin: string,
        public kurzbez: string,
        public bild: string,
        public beschreibung: string
      ) {}
}
```

This is my service to get it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { WassersportdetailRaw } from './wassersportdetail.interface';
import { Wassersportdetail } from './wassersportdetail.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService {
  api2 ='http://www.kalliany.at/SPG/getWassersport_withID.php?id=';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getWassersportDetail(id): Observable<Wassersportdetail> {
  return this.http
    .get<WassersportdetailRaw>(`${this.api2}`+id)
    .pipe(map(raws => this.provideWassersportDetailFrom(raws)));
 }

provideWassersportDetailFrom(raws: WassersportdetailRaw): Wassersportdetail {
  return new Wassersportdetail(
    raws.id,
    raws.sportart,
    raws.disziplin,
    raws.kurzbez,
    raws.bild,
    raws.beschreibung
  );
}
}
```

This is my html

```
<br>
<h1 align=center>Wassersportdetail</h1> 

<ul>  
    <button routerLink="/form0" class="btn btn-primary" id = "oben" >Zurück zur  Startseite!</button> 
    <br><br>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Sportart</td>
          <td>Disziplin</td>
          <td>Kurz Bezeichnung</td>
          <td>Bild</td>
          <td>beschreibung</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ sport.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ sport.sportart }}</td>
          <td>{{ sport.disziplin }}</td>
          <td>{{ sport.kurzbez }}</td>
          <td>{{ sport.bild }}</td>
          <td>{{ sport.beschreibung }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <img src="{{sport.bild}}" >
</ul>
```

**but the  part is not functioning how can I get the image?**

ANd it is just for a school project so I did not take everything very seriously dont mind the badly done things ^^

Comment: Well, `large/Kanu_01_large.jpg`is a **relative** URL. So it's resolved based on the URL of the current page, displayed in the browser address bar. You need to use the actual absolute URL of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path setted in `bild` field will concat with the active host in the browser.  So but the real images are in backend side I think. Get the absolute path from backend maybe static folders path or generated url from backend. Then concat the string the absolute lath and the `bild` field